# Difference between "const" outside component and "static" inside component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand why this works:

```
const ownStyle = { cursor: "pointer" };
class ThemeToggler extends React.Component {
    render() { return (<div style={ownStyle}>Toggle theme</div>; }
}
```

but why this doesn't:

```
class ThemeToggler extends React.Component {
    static ownStyle = { cursor: "pointer" };
    render() { return (<div style={this.ownStyle}>Toggle theme</div>); }
}
```

In the second case, the style attribute in the rendered HTML is even not created and I see no error in my debug terminal nor in the browser inspect section. Anyone has a clue on why this second code doesn't work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, the `ownStyle` property belongs to the **class** `ThemeToggler` rather than the instance of that class.

This means you should access it on the class `ThemeToggler` rather than using `this` (which refers to the current instance of that class):

```
class ThemeToggler extends React.Component {
    static ownStyle = { cursor: "pointer" };
    render() { return (<div style={ThemeToggler.ownStyle}>Toggle theme</div>); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am from C++ world, and I wouldn't have thought of that (in my backend world, from inside an instance of a class, the code knows everything which is in the class, being static or not. I'm a little surprised it's different here in JS).

Answer (score 0):

Static properties are not created per instance, they only exist directly on the class itself. `this` keyword inside class methods refers to the *instance* of the class (in the case of React a specific *instance* of a component), which doesn't contain static properties/methods.

You can access static properties directly via the class:

```
class ThemeToggler extends React.Component {
  static ownStyle = { cursor: "pointer" };
  render() { return (<div style={ThemeToggler.ownStyle}>Toggle theme</div>); }
  //-------------------------------^
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much TJ, you confirm what Sly answered a little earlier. It's so great to have such a helpful community ^^